# crash of a nb 22thMarch23 while it was ok 19thJan2023

Tags: python, git, google-colaboratory, jax

I have a problem  that I do not know how to tackle it. I have a nb on Colab that was working perfectly on CPU [Here is the working nb 19th Jan 23](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gOk9-DqZqF6xbdHM5GBopjOmMAKioSgD)

Then, I was looking to get a new nb working in the same condition (CPU)

1. Dealing with JAX 0.3.25 version I have pip install

```py
!pip install jax==0.3.25
!pip install jaxlib==0.3.25
```

then also pip install my repo at it was Jan 203, using the git commit "tag"

```py
!pip install -q git+https://<git-repo>@a3ecb7f
```

Now proceeding the same as the Jan nb, crashes
as you can see [HERE nb 22 March 23](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12jVn9LUDcF6eHqIpBLAN9Ccq0QVegPrE#scrollTo=Mt9PbcUmhszn)

My repo is a fork of an other repo done Nov. 2022.

Is there a reason why the March nb may crash due to some hidden changes? I'm not so confortable with git so may I was doing something wrong on Calob.

Help is warmly welcome.

Comment: The second colab link (showing the error) is not public. Speculating: a number of things have changed since january, including updated JAX versions, updated Python version in the Colab runtime, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the bug is, but I happen to know that in January the version of JAX on Colab was 0.3.25. I found that installing this version makes your notebook run without error:

```
!pip install jax==0.3.25 jaxlib==0.3.25
```

It's hard to say exactly what JAX change may have led to the error you're seeing. JAX's [CHANGELOG](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html)  summarizes the changes in recent versions.

Comment: Hi @jakevdp  Do you manage to run my nb w/o error! 

After your edit, I just do exactly as you that is to say make the pip install on a single line, while I was doing it in two separate lines. Does it make a difference ???

Comment: After my edit, I just do exactly as you  and it works with 0.3.25. 

I have investigate all the JAX releases and this is the  0.4.6 that fails ( I have opened the nb privilage)

Comment: I have not manage to get an install of the 0.4.5 to see if it is ok or not